# Python equivalent for tidyr::complete in R that allows specifying additional values

Tags: python, r, pandas, dplyr, pandas-groupby

I'm looking to re-create a R script and I am stuck on how to recreate this pipe in Python. I am analyzing the cumulative production of different factories and need to normalize their cumulative production time in order to compare.

The pipe looks like this:

```
Norm_hrs <- Cum_df%>%
  group_by(Name)%>%
  complete(Cum_hrs = seq(0,max(Cum_hrs),730.5))
```

It takes this:

```
Name        Cum_Hrs A   B           C
Factory 1   1       0   1.887861    3.775722
Factory 1   251     0   2104.335728 21932.57871
Factory 1   611     0   2324.586178 37498.99722
Factory 1   1208    0   4361.588197 65235.05541
Factory 2   48      0   1517.840244 6604.770432
Factory 2   163     0   3370.461172 17252.70972
Factory 2   822     0   13284.87786 71918.78308
Factory 2   1541    0   21476.93602 134569.0388
Factory 2   2285    0   32053.99192 225895.1477
Factory 2   3028    0   42299.41357 340798.6151
Factory 2   3699    0   50125.85599 462145.5438
Factory 2   4436    0   56715.74945 584474.9989
```

And Turns it into this:

```
Name        Cum_Hrs A   B           C
Factory 1   1       0   1.887861    3.775722
Factory 1   251     0   2104.335728 21932.57871
Factory 1   611     0   2324.586178 37498.99722
Factory 1   730.5   NA  NA          NA
Factory 1   1208    0   4361.588197 65235.05541
Factory 2   48      0   1517.840244 6604.770432
Factory 2   163     0   3370.461172 17252.70972
Factory 2   730.5   NA  NA          NA
Factory 2   822     0   13284.87786 71918.78308
Factory 2   1461    NA  NA          NA
Factory 2   1541    0   21476.93602 134569.0388
Factory 2   2091.5  NA  NA          NA
Factory 2   2285    0   32053.99192 225895.1477
Factory 2   2922    NA  NA          NA
Factory 2   3028    0   42299.41357 340798.6151
```

This in turn allows me to interpolate the values of the NAs in the DataFrame for normalized time steps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply concatenate a sequential data frame of all unique *Name* with incremental *Cum_Hrs* value:

```
seq_df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'Name': i, 'Cum_Hrs': np.arange(0, max(g['Cum_Hrs']), 730.5)})
                     for i,g in df.groupby(['Name'])])

final_df = (pd.concat([df, seq_df], sort=True)
              .sort_values(['Name', 'Cum_Hrs'])
              .reset_index(drop=True)
              .reindex(columns=df.columns)
            )

print(final_df)
#          Name  Cum_Hrs    A             B              C
# 0   Factory 1      0.0  NaN           NaN            NaN
# 1   Factory 1      1.0  0.0      1.887861       3.775722
# 2   Factory 1    251.0  0.0   2104.335728   21932.578710
# 3   Factory 1    611.0  0.0   2324.586178   37498.997220
# 4   Factory 1    730.5  NaN           NaN            NaN
# 5   Factory 1   1208.0  0.0   4361.588197   65235.055410
# 6   Factory 2      0.0  NaN           NaN            NaN
# 7   Factory 2     48.0  0.0   1517.840244    6604.770432
# 8   Factory 2    163.0  0.0   3370.461172   17252.709720
# 9   Factory 2    730.5  NaN           NaN            NaN
# 10  Factory 2    822.0  0.0  13284.877860   71918.783080
# 11  Factory 2   1461.0  NaN           NaN            NaN
# 12  Factory 2   1541.0  0.0  21476.936020  134569.038800
# 13  Factory 2   2191.5  NaN           NaN            NaN
# 14  Factory 2   2285.0  0.0  32053.991920  225895.147700
# 15  Factory 2   2922.0  NaN           NaN            NaN
# 16  Factory 2   3028.0  0.0  42299.413570  340798.615100
# 17  Factory 2   3652.5  NaN           NaN            NaN
# 18  Factory 2   3699.0  0.0  50125.855990  462145.543800
# 19  Factory 2   4383.0  NaN           NaN            NaN
# 20  Factory 2   4436.0  0.0  56715.749450  584474.998900
```

---

A similar process can be handled in base R. Usually it is easier to translate base R (non-tidyverse) to Pandas:

- `seq` ==> `np.arange`
- `by` ==> `pd.DataFrame.groupby`
- `data.frame` ==> `pd.DataFrame`
- `do.call` + `rbind` ==> `pd.concat`
- `order` ==> `pd.sort_values`
- `row.names=NULL` ==> `pd.reset_index()`

**R**

```r
# BUILD SEQUENCE DATA FRAME
seq_df = do.call(rbind, by(df, df$Name, function(sub) 
                              data.frame(Name = sub$Name[[1]], 
                                         Cum_Hrs = seq(0, max(sub$Cum_Hrs), 730.5),
                                         A = NA, B = NA, C = NA))
                )

# CONCATENATE REFERENCING EVERY COLUMN
final_df = rbind(df, seq_df)

# SORT ROWS AND RESET ROW NAMES
final_df = with(final_df, data.frame(final_df[order(Name, Cum_Hrs),], row.names=NULL))

final_df
```

[Rextester Demo](https://rextester.com/EHS27591)

Answer (score 1):

Here would be a working way around it - though probably not the most straightforward:

```
reps = (df.groupby("Name")["Cum_Hrs"].agg("max") / 730.5).astype(int)

# reps:
Name
Factory1    1
Factory2    6
Name: Cum_Hrs, dtype: int64
```

Expand this into the two columns you want filled and merge it back with original df:

```
newdf = pd.DataFrame({"Name": np.repeat(reps.index.values, reps.values),
                      "Cum_Hrs": np.hstack([np.arange(e)+1 for e in reps.values]) * 730.5})
df = pd.concat([df, newdf], ignore_index=True).sort(["Name", "Cum_Hrs"])[df.columns]

# merged df:
        Name  Cum_Hrs    A             B              C
0   Factory1      1.0  0.0      1.887861       3.775722
1   Factory1    251.0  0.0   2104.335728   21932.578710
2   Factory1    611.0  0.0   2324.586178   37498.997220
12  Factory1    730.5  NaN           NaN            NaN
3   Factory1   1208.0  0.0   4361.588197   65235.055410
4   Factory2     48.0  0.0   1517.840244    6604.770432
5   Factory2    163.0  0.0   3370.461172   17252.709720
13  Factory2    730.5  NaN           NaN            NaN
6   Factory2    822.0  0.0  13284.877860   71918.783080
14  Factory2   1461.0  NaN           NaN            NaN
7   Factory2   1541.0  0.0  21476.936020  134569.038800
15  Factory2   2191.5  NaN           NaN            NaN
8   Factory2   2285.0  0.0  32053.991920  225895.147700
16  Factory2   2922.0  NaN           NaN            NaN
9   Factory2   3028.0  0.0  42299.413570  340798.615100
17  Factory2   3652.5  NaN           NaN            NaN
10  Factory2   3699.0  0.0  50125.855990  462145.543800
18  Factory2   4383.0  NaN           NaN            NaN
11  Factory2   4436.0  0.0  56715.749450  584474.998900
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to replicate in python using [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar):

```py
>>> from datar.all import f, tribble, group_by, complete, seq, max, as_integer
[2021-06-24 16:15:59][datar][WARNING] Builtin name "max" has been overriden by datar.
>>> 
>>> Cum_df = tribble(
...   f.Name,      f.Cum_hrs, f.A,   f.B,           f.C,
...   "Factory 1", 1,         0,     1.887861,      3.775722,
...   "Factory 1", 251,       0,     2104.335728,   21932.57871,
...   "Factory 1", 611,       0,     2324.586178,   37498.99722,
...   "Factory 1", 1208,      0,     4361.588197,   65235.05541,
...   "Factory 2", 48,        0,     1517.840244,   6604.770432,
...   "Factory 2", 163,       0,     3370.461172,   17252.70972,
...   "Factory 2", 822,       0,     13284.87786,   71918.78308,
...   "Factory 2", 1541,      0,     21476.93602,   134569.0388,
...   "Factory 2", 2285,      0,     32053.99192,   225895.1477,
...   "Factory 2", 3028,      0,     42299.41357,   340798.6151,
...   "Factory 2", 3699,      0,     50125.85599,   462145.5438,
...   "Factory 2", 4436,      0,     56715.74945,   584474.9989,
... )
>>> 
>>> Cum_df >> \
...   group_by(f.Name) >> \
...   complete(Cum_hrs=as_integer(seq(0, max(f.Cum_hrs), 730.5)))
         Name   Cum_hrs         A             B              C
     <object> <float64> <float64>     <float64>      <float64>
0   Factory 1       0.0       NaN           NaN            NaN
1   Factory 1     730.0       NaN           NaN            NaN
2   Factory 2       0.0       NaN           NaN            NaN
3   Factory 2     730.0       NaN           NaN            NaN
4   Factory 2    1461.0       NaN           NaN            NaN
5   Factory 2    2191.0       NaN           NaN            NaN
6   Factory 2    2922.0       NaN           NaN            NaN
7   Factory 2    3652.0       NaN           NaN            NaN
8   Factory 2    4383.0       NaN           NaN            NaN
9   Factory 1       1.0       0.0      1.887861       3.775722
10  Factory 1     251.0       0.0   2104.335728   21932.578710
11  Factory 1     611.0       0.0   2324.586178   37498.997220
12  Factory 1    1208.0       0.0   4361.588197   65235.055410
13  Factory 2      48.0       0.0   1517.840244    6604.770432
14  Factory 2     163.0       0.0   3370.461172   17252.709720
15  Factory 2     822.0       0.0  13284.877860   71918.783080
16  Factory 2    1541.0       0.0  21476.936020  134569.038800
17  Factory 2    2285.0       0.0  32053.991920  225895.147700
18  Factory 2    3028.0       0.0  42299.413570  340798.615100
19  Factory 2    3699.0       0.0  50125.855990  462145.543800
20  Factory 2    4436.0       0.0  56715.749450  584474.998900

[Groups: Name (n=2)]
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of the [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) package.